# Get raw predictions from Vowpal Wabbit in daemon mode

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I'm starting Vowpal Wabbit in daemon mode with the following command:

`vw --loss_function hinge --ect 250 --quiet --passes 5 -b 25 --daemon --port 10001 --pid_file pidfile`

This works well and I'm able to get predictions by connecting to the socket and sending my data and reading an answer.

My question is, is it possible to also get the raw predictions passed over the socket when in daemon mode?

Instead of only 
`1.000000` as an answer, I'd like to get something `1:-2.31425 2:-3.98557 3:-3.97967` instead.

Comment: i'm stuck on the same exact issue (but using -oaa), did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never managed to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this with VW currently. The best option is to write the raw predictions to a file and read from that file.

```
vw --loss_function hinge -r raw_pred --ect 250 --quiet --passes 5 -b 25 --daemon --port 10001 --pid_file pidfile
```